# Why the main class could not be found?

Tags: java, restlet

I have a single class using import from Restlet framework. The class is compiled successfully from command line, but it could not be run due to Could not find or load main class staticfilesexample.TestStaticFiles error. This is the file:

```
public class TestStaticFiles extends ServerResource {

public static final String ROOT_URI = "file:///D:/myJava/restletTutorials/src/staticfilesexample/testdir";
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    Component component = new Component();
    component.getServers().add(Protocol.HTTP, 8111);

    component.getClients().add(Protocol.FILE);

    Application application = new Application() {
        //Создание точки входа запросов
        @Override
        public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
            return new Directory(getContext(), ROOT_URI);
        }
    };

    component.getDefaultHost().attach(application);
    component.start();
}

}
```

And this is the command line command:

```
java -cp bin;"D:\myJava\restlet-jse-2.3.9\restlet-jse-2.3.9\lib\org.restlet.org" staticfilesexample.TestStaticFiles
```

And this is the files locations:

```
D:.
├───bin
│   └───staticfilesexample
└───src
    └───staticfilesexample
        └───testdir
```

Comment: You don't have `staticfilesexample` in the class path.

Comment: But it should not be there, should it? Because bin is present.  Any way I tried. Nothing changed.

Comment: It seems so, try putting entire class path `"bin;D:\..."` in quotes.

Comment: I've got it. Stupid mistake in archive name - org.restlet.org instead of org.restlet.jar. Sorry.

Comment: I noticed that before, but I thought that it was a directory name :)